# How can I get an XLL from a DLL?

Tags: c++, excel, dll, codeblocks, xll

Can anybody give me some links or explain me how to build an XLL from a DLL (for Excel)?

I *cannot* use Visual C++, so I rely on CodeBlocks + GCC.

So far I have the source code and I obtained a DLL from it. **How can I get the XLL from the DLL?**

This seems to be the last step, but I cannot find complete documentation about it. Even on [Microsoft web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687861.aspx) there is not much about it.

I would like to have the step-by-step explanation to do this conversion...

Thank you.

Platform: 64 bit Windows 7, 32 bit Excel 2010, CodeBlocks, MinGW/GCC

Comment: @JaredPar: An XLL is a DLL that can be loaded by Excel.

Comment: @Pietro, have you looked at the rest of the SDK documentation you linked to? For example, this part: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687850.aspx. I think you're most of the way there.

Comment: @jtolle: I read it, but it does not mention XLLs at all...

Comment: @Pietro, perhaps combine that page with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687861.aspx. The point is that to make a DLL into an XLL you have to have it export certain functions in the right way. But the SDK should contain all the information you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty trivial really. Simply rename your DLL. That's right, just change the extension. A XLL file is nothing else than a DLL renamed to signify it's meant to be an Excel add-in. See [step 11 of this tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178474).

Comment: Done, thank you. It does not work yet, but the reason must be a different one... I flag yours as the accepted answer, but in case of problems I will be back, and I may unflag it. So, do not go too far in the meantime ;-)

Comment: It's a little bit more than a DLL. It has a DLL format/layout, but implements a few standard Excel function requirements (eg. xlAutoOpen, xlAutoClose etc). I think there are about 4-5 of these functions. If you take a look at XLW framework, you can see exactly what's going on with .xll files - it's an awesome framework for building your own .xll files.

Answer (score 4):

An xll is a dll with certain well-know functions. When you open an xll in Excel it dynamically loads `int xlAutoOpen(void)` and calls that to register your user defined functions.

Save yourself a heap of trouble and just use http://xll.codeplex.com.

Comment: I believe this is a more accurate answer than the accepted one.

Comment: Looks like it moved to here: https://github.com/keithalewis/xll12